# Porting C# AES Encryption to Javascript for Node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, aes

Looking for help to port below C# code into Node.js using crypto or equivalent module.

```
private string password="FlU4c8yQKLkYuFwsgyU4LFeIf7m3Qwy+poMBdULEMqw=";
private byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("##oEDA102ExChAnGe99#$#");
Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
string pdbStr = Convert.ToBase64String(pdb.GetBytes(32));
Console.WriteLine(pdbStr);
encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
```

Tried porting into javascript as below, but the resulted value are not the same.

```
var password = "FlU4c8yQKLkYuFwsgyU4LFeIf7m3Qwy+poMBdULEMqw=";
var salt = "##oEDA102ExChAnGe99#$#";
var pdbBytes = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(password, 'base64'), new Buffer(salt, 'base64'), 1000, 32);
var pdbStr = new Buffer(pdbBytes).toString('base64')
console.log("pdbStr", pdbStr);
```

Console output:
C# - GZlqgdLbMQ753dTmx1nlJ6HgdabTjW1CeCSoIYkLM4E=
JS - tuDsZJEEwxyXP7RvuYVxGmDy20AvMJAqkLoXX78sEU8=

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what are password and salt ...

Comment: Hi, password = FlU4c8yQKLkYuFwsgyU4LFeIf7m3Qwy+poMBdULEMqw= and salt = ##oEDA102ExChAnGe99#$#

Comment: I didn't mean the values, I meant what type of data are they ... password looks like base64 encoded data, salt is too, but is multiple "values" by the look of it - do both libraries expect base64 encoded data for password? are `password` and `salt` both Strings in C#?

Comment: one thing to try, since `password` is obviously base64 ... `var pdbBytes = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(password, 'base64'), new Buffer(salt), 1000, 32);`

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, thanks for your reply. Tried as you suggested but the resulted value are still not same. Edited my code sample, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: you're not getting any errors about `digest`? what is `crypto`

Comment: No errors for digest. var crypto = require('crypto');

Comment: How odd. Your code didn't work at all in node 9.4.0. I needed to add "sha1" to the parameters

Answer (score 0):

these codes parts  are generating same the result.

but i did not get 'GZlqgdLbMQ753dTmx1nlJ6HgdabTjW1CeCSoIYkLM4E=' result from c#.

**c#**

```
    byte[] password= Convert.FromBase64String("FlU4c8yQKLkYuFwsgyU4LFeIf7m3Qwy+poMBdULEMqw=");
    byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("##oEDA102ExChAnGe99#$#");
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password,salt,1000);
    string pdbStr =Convert.ToBase64String(pdb.GetBytes(32));
    Console.WriteLine(pdbStr);
    //outpu : RMqDMSV6d8uT2NicGM212r3KMFt7ZsOI2q8+0Rr0WZQ=
```

**JS**

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var password = "FlU4c8yQKLkYuFwsgyU4LFeIf7m3Qwy+poMBdULEMqw=";
var salt = "##oEDA102ExChAnGe99#$#";
crypto.DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'base64';
var pdbBytes = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password,'base64'), salt, 1000, 32,'sha1');
var pdbStr = new Buffer(pdbBytes).toString()
console.log("pdbStr", pdbStr);
//outpu : RMqDMSV6d8uT2NicGM212r3KMFt7ZsOI2q8+0Rr0WZQ=
```

Comment: Hi @levent, thanks for your help. It helped to solve my issue. Earlier in C# code I was calling GetBytes more than once which caused the difference in the result.